# How can i make TCP server run in parallel mode to send without waiting for reply?

Tags: c

Am Trying to build a TCP server that can send and receive data. My code works well but I noticed that the server will have to wait until the server replies before sending another data. How can i make the server to receive multiple requests at a time and reply to them later.

I want something that can make the server to receive data and keep mute, then later reply to the data later (if am correct). The server is running on 127.0.0.1 at port 2019. Lastly, i need to add signalling to prevent Control-C from exiting the program.

To start the client use
./client 127.0.0.1 2019

My Server code,

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 2019

#define MAXIMUM_CONNECTION 100

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int main() {


    int sockfd, clientSock, bytes, index = 0;

    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr, clientAddr;

    memset(&serverAddr, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr));

    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) >= 0) {
        printf("\033[0;31m");
        printf("\n successfully binded the address to socket");
    }

    listen(sockfd, MAXIMUM_CONNECTION);

    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE], message[BUFFER_SIZE];

    while(1) {

        socklen_t clientAddrLen = sizeof(clientAddr);

        if(clientSock = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &clientAddr, &clientAddrLen)) {
            printf("\033[0;31m");
            printf("\n client accepted");
        }

        memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
        memset(message, '\0', sizeof(message));

        bytes = recv(clientSock, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE - 1, 0);

        buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = '\0';

        printf("\n Received data: ");

        fputs(buffer, stdout);

        printf("\n Type data to send: ");


        while((message[index++] = getchar()) != '\n');

        message[BUFFER_SIZE] = '\n';

        send(clientSock, message, sizeof(message), 0);

    }

    shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_RDWR);

}
```

My client Code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

// #define PORT 10900

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("\033[1;31m");
        printf("Expecting 2 arguments %d given", argc - 1);
        exit(0);
    }

    char *inputServer = argv[1];

    int port = atoi(argv[2]), index = 0, activityCount = 0;

    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE], message[BUFFER_SIZE];

    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;

    int sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP), bytes;

    if (sockfd >= 0)
    {
        printf("\033[0;32m");
        printf("\n[%d] socket successfully created\n", activityCount++);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\033[1;31m");
        printf("\nFailed to create socket, client exiting\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    memset(&serverAddr, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr));

    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(inputServer);

    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(port);

    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) >= 0)
    {
        printf("\033[0;32m");
        printf("\n[%d] client successfully connected to %s on port %d\n", activityCount++, inputServer, port);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\033[0;31m");
        printf("\nFailed to connecting to server, client exiting\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    while (1)
    {

        memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
        memset(message, '\0', sizeof(buffer));

        printf("Type your message here & press enter key: ");

        while ((message[index++] = getchar()) != '\n')
            ;

        message[BUFFER_SIZE] = '\0';

        if (send(sockfd, message, sizeof(message), 0) > 0)
        {
            printf("\033[0;32m");
            printf("\n[%d] client sent message to server\n", activityCount++);
            printf("\nMessage Sent: (%s)\n", message);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\033[1;31m");
            printf("\nFailed to sending to server, client exiting\n");
            exit(-1);
        }

        bytes = recv(sockfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE - 1, 0);

        buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = '\0';

        if (bytes > 0)
        {
            printf("\033[0;32m");

            printf("\n[%d] client received message from server\n", activityCount++);
            printf("\nMessage Received: (%s)\n", buffer);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\033[0;31m");
            printf("\nFailed to receive from server, client exiting\n");
        }
    }

    shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_RDWR);
}
```

Comment: read on threads. you can use pthread library to launch a new thread for every new connection and handle it asynchronously. read especially on pthread_create function. you'll need to move some of your variables to the thread worker main function.

Answer (score 0):

**TCP Buffers**

The TCP stack will provide large buffers to hold data in transit. Those buffers are usually much larger than buffers used for pipes. From a practical point of view, `sending` of data in the sample code above (up to 1K data) will not result in any 'waiting' - data will be buffered, and execution of the server will continue, even if the client does not immediately read the data.

To some extent, this is similar to writing to files - application `write` will go into system buffers, and the application can usually continue to run, while the system flushes out the changes to the disk.

**Handling CTRL/C**

Add a call to to capture (or ignore) SIGINT

```
#include <signal.h>

void int_handler(int sig) {
   fprintf(stderr, "Ignoring Signal %d\n", sig) ;
   return ;
}

int main(...)
{
   signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN) ;      // Ignore Signal
   signal(SIGINT, int_handler) ;  // Custom hander
}
```